# Mocking named imports and constructors ES6 & Ava

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, ava

I have a class constructor, with a function I want to stub:

```
class Service {
  constructor(){}
  async someFunction() {
    try {
    // does stuff
    }
    catch (e) {}
  }
}
```

In the file I want to test, this is imported an used like so:

```
const { Service } = require('something')
const newService = new Service('xyz')
```

I'm struggling to get this to import & stub correctly in my tests.

Currently am importing like this:

```
t.context.service = {
  Service: class Service {
    constructor () {
      this.someFunction = sinon.stub()
    }
  }
}
```

This import seems to work, but then I can't get a reference back to it through the constructed version. Any help on this one?

I want to be able to make an assertion like:

```
t.true(t.context.service.Service.someFunction.calledOnce)
```

Answer (score 1):

AVA doesn't provide any stubbing. Have a look at https://github.com/testdouble/testdouble.js/ or http://sinonjs.org/.

Comment: Yeah of course, I am using Sinon for stubbing as you can see in my question. Ran out of characters in the question title!